# IPSec tunnel on Google Compute Virtual Machine

Tags: google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016, windows-firewall, ipsec

I am trying to setup an IPSec tunnel on my virtual machine on Google Compute Engine and it seems all my traffic is blocked. Even though I have open the necessary ports on both the Windows Server 2016 server and Google's Firewall. Question I have is it possible to setup the VPN tunnel on the server it self or should I make use of the Hybrid Connectivity VPN or something else? I have the same setup on a dedicated server but just can't get Main Mode and or Quick Mode functioning at all.
PS I have setup many iPSec tunnels on stand alone server just not on a virtual server using Google Compute Engine.

Thanks in advance for your help on this one.

Comment: GCP provides a VPN connection mechanism here ... https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview.  Unless you have a need that hasn't been desribed, I would use this as the GCP end of the VPN.

Comment: Regarding your query on possibility to setup the VPN tunnel on the server  would like to add that you could use Strongswan VPN software to [set up a VPN gateway on one of your instances](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/special-configurations#settingupvpn). For most users, Google recommends that you use [Cloud VPN](https://cloud.google.com/vpn/docs/concepts/overview) instead of Strongswan. 
With Cloud VPN, you don't need to create and configure an instance to run VPN software. Use Strongswan in cases where Cloud VPN doesn't provide required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to set up IPSec VPN server with Debian 10 virtual machine, on Google Compute Engine.
Here's what I did:

1. While creating virtual machine instance (Debian 10 for example), in "Network interface" window set option "IP forwarding" to "ON";
2. On "VPC network" page create firewall rule with open ports: "udp: 500, 4500";
3. Use this script to setup VPN software:

```
wget https://git.io/vpnsetup -O vpnsetup.sh && sudo sh vpnsetup.sh
```

It will generate credentials needed for next step. They look like this: "Server IP: ****", "IPsec PSK: ****", "Username: ****", "Password: ****".

4. For client configuration use credentials generated from above step and IPsec/XAuth protocol while setting vpn connection.
   Look here if you encounter problems: https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn/blob/master/docs/clients-xauth.md

Check this guide "IPsec VPN Server Auto Setup Scripts" for more information:
https://github.com/hwdsl2/setup-ipsec-vpn